# Write a lambda expression to perform a calulcation on an list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a List/IEnumerable of objects and I'd like to perform a calculation on some of them.

e.g.
myList.Where(f=>f.Calculate==true).Calculate();

to update myList, based on the Where clause, so that the required calulcation is performed and the entire list updated as appropriate.

The list contains "lines" where an amount is either in Month1, Month2, Month3...Month12, Year1, Year2, Year3-5 or "Long Term"
Most lines are fixed and always fall into one of these months, but some "lines" are calulcated based upon their "Maturity Date".

Oh, and just to complicate things!  the list (at the moment) is of an anonymous type from a couple of linq queries.  I could make it a concrete class if required though, but I'd prefer not to if I can avoid it.

So, I'd like to call a method that works on only the calculated lines, and puts the correct amount into the correct "month".
I'm not worried about the calculation logic, but rather how to get this into an easily readable method that updates the list without, ideally, returning a new list.

[Is it possible to write a lambda extension method to do both the calculation AND the where - or is this overkill anyway as Where() already exists?]

Comment: LINQ is for querying (filtering, projecting, aggregating, etc.). Using LINQ queries to obtain side effects is a gross abuse of LINQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, if you want to update the list *in place*, I would just use a simple loop.  It will be much simpler to follow and maintain:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.Count;++i)
{
     if (list[i].ShouldCalculate)
         list[i] = list[i].Calculate();
}
```

This, at least, is much more obvious that it's going to update.  LINQ has the expectation of performing a *query*, not mutating the data.

---

If you really want to use LINQ for this, you can - but it will still require a copy if you want to have a `List<T>` as your results:

```
myList = myList.Select(f => f.ShouldCalculate ? f.Calculate() : f).ToList();
```

This would call your `Calculate()` method as needed, and copy the original when not needed.  It does require a copy to create a new `List<T>`, though, as you mentioned that was a requirement (in comments).

However, my personal preference would still be to use a loop in this case.  I find the intent much more clear - plus, you avoid the unnecessary copy operation.

---

Edit #2:

Given this comment:

> Oh, and just to complicate things! the list (at the moment) is of an anonymous type from a couple of linq queries

If you really want to use LINQ style syntax, I would recommend just not calling `ToList()` on your original queries.  If you leave them in their original, `IEnumerable<T>` form, you can easily do my second option above, but on the original query:

```
var myList = query.Select(f => f.ShouldCalculate ? f.Calculate() : f).ToList();
```

This has the advantage of only constructing the list one time, and preventing the copy, as the original sequence will not get evaluated until this operation.

Comment: @Joe: No, ShouldCalculate is assumed to be a property of the item... just as it is in the question.

Comment: Thanks:  I need this as a list<T> later on, so would ,myList.Where(..).ToList().Foreach(x=>Calulate(x)) be a more sensible approach?

Comment: @BlueChippy: No - if you have a list (myList), and loop through it, it'll still be a `List<T>` - Using LINQ for this is really not appropriate, IMO.  Using ForEach after the where, btw, will not include the non-matching elements in your results, as well as doing the copy you wish to avoid...

Comment: @BlueChippy: No. `ForEach` is an abomination.

Comment: @Joe: I was copying the OP - but then realized (while you were commenting) that the property in the original question couldn't be used, as it had the same name as the method ;)

Comment: @Jason:  Could you explain why not to use ForEach()?  It seems very simple and accessible - so why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: @BlueChippy: I edited to show a cleaner approach using LINQ - for the ForEach<T> debate, I'd recommend reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx   - Basically, it's causing side effects in a method that looks like it should have no side effects...

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is mostly geared around side-effect-free queries, and anonymous types themselves are immutable (although of course they can maintain references to mutable types).

Given that you want to mutate the list in place, LINQ isn't a great fit.

As per Reed's suggestion, I would use a straight `for` loop. However, if you want to perform different calculations at different points, you could encapsulate this:

```
public static void Recalculate<T>(IList<T> list,
                                  Func<T, bool> shouldCalculate,
                                  Func<T, T> calculation)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (shouldCalculate(items[i]))
        {
            items[i] = calculation(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to use this in a fluid way, you could make it return the list - but I would personally be against that, as it would then *look* like it was side-effect-free like LINQ.

And like Reed, I'd *also* prefer to do this by creating a new sequence...

Answer (score 0):

`Select` doesn't copy or clone the objects it passes to the passed delegate, any state changes to that object will be reflected through the reference in the container (unless it is a value type).

So updating reference types is not a problem.

To replace the objects (or when working with value types<sup>1</sup>) this are more complex and there is no inbuilt solution with LINQ. A for loop is clearest (as with the other answers).

---

<sup>1</sup> Remembering, of course, that [mutable value types are evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx).